# Develop the Python function normdist(x, mu ,sigma)

Tags: python, math, statistics

I do not understand this homework question i have received,our task is to develop the Python function  normdist(x,mu,sigma) , which evaluates the multivariate
Gaussian probability density function for the  k ­dimensional vector  x , the mean vector  μ  and the covariance
matrix  Σ . In the special case where  k = 1 , this function evaluates the univariate Gaussian probability
density function for the scalar  x , the mean  μ  and the standard deviation  σ .

My attempt is below:

```
def normcdf(x, mu, sigma):
    t = x-mu;
    y = 0.5*erfcc(-t/(sigma*sqrt(2.0)));
    if y>1.0:
        y = 1.0;
    return y

def normpdf(x, mu, sigma):
    u = (x-mu)/abs(sigma)
    y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)**k*abs(sigma)))*exp(-u*u/2)
    return y

def normdist(x, mu, sigma, k):
    if k:
        y = normcdf(x,mu,sigma)
    else:
        y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma)
    return y
```

Above code credited to Cerin

How do i handle the case of k =1 ?

Comment: So... what's your _question_?

Comment: Have a successfully developed the python function normdist??

Comment: You already _have_ a `normdist` function...  but you haven't told us what's wrong with it.  (Also, `k` does not appear in your code anywhere, so I don't see why you think it will affect anything's return value.)  Please (re-)read "[ask]", and then [edit] your question so that it's clear what you're asking.  If there's a bug you're trying to fix, then make sure you provide a [mcve].

Comment: You could start by accepting a parameter named `k`, and then doing something with it.

Comment: Sorry guys, i have changed it up now,